# Trying to understand why DrRacket highlights some of my cond clauses

Tags: racket

Exercise 42 from the second edition of [How to Design Programs](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_one.html#%28part._sec~3aenums%29) explains that DrRacket highlights the last two `cond` clauses in the code below because the test cases do not cover all possible cases.

```
; TrafficLight -> TrafficLight
; given state s, determine the next state of the traffic light

(check-expect (traffic-light-next "red") "green")

(define (traffic-light-next s)
  (cond
    [(string=? "red" s) "green"]
    [(string=? "green" s) "yellow"]
    [(string=? "yellow" s) "red"]))
```

My understanding is that an `else` clause at the end should cover the remaining cases, so I tried replacing the last expressions:

```
(define (traffic-light-next s)
  (cond
    [(string=? "red" s) "green"]
    [(string=? "green" s) "yellow"]
    [(string=? "yellow" s) "red"]
    [else "green"]))
```

This does not solve the highlighting problem.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the purpose of the highlighting. The point of the code coverage tool is to make sure you have enough *test cases* (i.e., `check-expect`s) to cover all the code you have written rather than ensuring that your `cond` clauses cover all the cases of your data definition. In your snippet, your `check-expect` is only testing the `"red"` case. You can get rid of the highlight by writing `check-expect`s for the other two cases of your data definition.

Also note that you actually do not want to write an `else` case here because your data definition for a `TrafficLight` only contains three cases. You can't test your `else` case without violating your signature/contract.